# Can ARIMA be used to forecast trend in time series data?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, arima, autoregressive, moving-average

I am new to ARIMA.
I have a time series data that has a negative trend.I need to predict its value for the upcoming time period.
I know that one of the steps in ARIMA is to de-trend data through differencing.
My question is that wouldn't the forecast be wrong, since this method assumes there is no trend in the data, when in fact there is a negative trend? How would the forecast be different from a forecast on a similar data with no trend?
And in general, why is de trending even done? 
If the data had trend, why would you ignore that and do a forecast after removing the trend?

Comment: ARIMA detrends a time series through regression and parameters, therefore those parameters are what you use for forecasting.

Comment: If your trend that you eyeballed is the result of an unit root process, then your series will not be stationary. Any standard estimation/hypothesis testing method for a non stationary process will not be correct. ARIMA can only model stationary process. Of course, if your trend is deterministic, then you can include a $at$ term in your model and estimate the $a$ parameter along with your ARIMA parameters.